# High CPU temperature

Tags: temperature, amd-processor, sensors

My CPU (AMD FX-6300) temp sensor (k10temp-pci-00c3) reports extreme temperatures even when opening a browser or playing a video. This cause the system malfunction. It was working fine before.

```
k10temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:       +176.6°C  (high = +70.0°C)
                       (crit = +85.0°C, hyst = +83.0°C)

f71869a-isa-0e80
Adapter: ISA adapter
+3.3V:         3.30 V  
in1:           1.22 V  
in2:           0.00 V  
in3:           0.00 V  
in4:           0.00 V  
in5:         864.00 mV 
in6:           1.10 V  
3VSB:          3.20 V  
Vbat:          3.25 V  
fan1:        1915 RPM
fan2:           0 RPM  ALARM
fan3:           0 RPM  ALARM
temp1:        +39.0°C  (high = +255.0°C, hyst = +251.0°C)  ALARM (CRIT)
                       (crit = +255.0°C, hyst = +251.0°C)  sensor = transistor
temp2:        +76.0°C  (high = +255.0°C, hyst = +247.0°C)  ALARM
                       (crit = +80.0°C, hyst = +72.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
temp3:        +37.0°C  (high = +255.0°C, hyst = +253.0°C)  ALARM (CRIT)
                       (crit = +255.0°C, hyst = +253.0°C)  sensor = transistor

fam15h_power-pci-00c4
Adapter: PCI adapter
power1:       94.68 W  (crit =  94.99 W)
```

My system information. I have kernel installed from [https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/)

```
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS x86_64 
Host: MS-7641 3.0 
Kernel: 6.3.13-060313-generic 
Uptime: 1 hour, 25 mins 
Packages: 3044 (dpkg), 34 (flatpak), 25 (snap) 
Shell: bash 5.1.16 
Resolution: 1920x1080 
DE: GNOME 42.9 
WM: Mutter 
WM Theme: Adwaita 
Theme: Arc-Dark [GTK2/3] 
Icons: Flat-Remix-Blue-Dark [GTK2/3] 
Terminal: gnome-terminal 
CPU: AMD FX-6300 (6) @ 3.500GHz 
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 
Memory: 3634MiB / 15979MiB
```

Comment: Blocked/n9nworking fan? Dust inside the computer?

Comment: @waltinator no physical problems.